# Multicollinearity to be assessed item wise or construct wise

Tags: regression, correlation, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

In order to check multicollinearity, do I have to combine items for the same construct and assess the correlation table for the constructs, OR do I have to check the item wise correlation table?

Answer (score 1):

Neither one.  Collinearity is a problem in regression. It involves all the independent variables that are in a particular regression.  It can be checked by using condition indexes (my preferred method) or variance inflation factors. There is also the `perturb` package in R, which is a very interesting way of checking it.